# Connection error while installing mongodb on fedora 28

Tags: mongodb, installation

I have been trying to install Mongodb but it keeps failing midway. When the download is complete, installation fails with a connection error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-08-17T12:26:33.340+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-08-17T12:26:33.340+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

What I've tried:
1. Changing the port:
`mongo --port 4332`
but it doesn't connect still:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:4332/
2018-08-17T12:32:55.743+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:4332, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-08-17T12:32:55.743+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:4332, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

2. Reinstalling the DB shows up as complete but I still can't start it. Check out the screenshot

[image: An image showing an error while installing mongodb]

3. Checking for any config files in `/etc/mongo*` or `/var/lib/`: there is none.

Comment: Looks like you're forgetting to [start the server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

Comment: There's no mongo service available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Fedora treats mongo and mongod as two separate packages. While on most distributions you can install both services in a single bundle, on Fedora you have to install them separately.
`sudo dnf install mongodb mongodb-server`
Then you can start the service with `mongod`.